# Need help getting my ssh keys to work on a digital ocean droplet

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

When creating the new droplet I check the SSH option and paste my public key (that works fine on my AWS) Droplet but unable to login to new droplet. Both instances are using ubuntu. From reading the documentation, I understand that if SSH keys are provide at the creation of an instance, no email with root password is sent.  Not sure why I am being prompted for password. Assistance would be appreciated.

here is the session on my attempt to login:

```
TLOMBARD-M-T8T8:.ssh tlombard$ ssh root@107.170.209.13
The authenticity of host '107.170.209.13 (107.170.209.13)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:CsusP0faav9SqEfSXpXpMjeEEp2GXrT77OT35x3TJco.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '107.170.209.13' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@107.170.209.13's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@107.170.209.13's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Answer (score 4):

First ensure that you are typing your password correctly, then update your *sshd_config* file enabling Password authentication.

On your ubuntu cli execute: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Then update Password authentication line from `PasswordAuthontication: no` to `PasswordAuthentication:yes`

Restart your ssh service executing `sudo service ssh restart`

Answer (score 3):

You need to check your SSH configuration on your Droplet.

- Log in via console (on the Digital Ocean website)
- su (to become root)
- edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Search for the setting `PermitRootLogin` and set it to:

  `PermitRootLogin: without-password`
- Also check the `PasswordAuthentication` and make sure it is set to:

  `PasswordAuthentication: no`

The `PermitRootLogin` ensures that SSH is expecting a keyed login for root.  I think that is all you need, but it doesn't hurt to set the PasswordAuthentication as well, which sets keyed only for all users.

Be sure to run

```
systemctl reload sshd
```

This will restart SSH with the new settings, for ubuntu 16.04.  (I think for 14.04 it was `service ssh restart`).

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested.  but ssh is still prompting for password-    Is reboot required?

Comment: @TimothyLombard, sorry about that, I forgot to add that you can reload the SSH service to load the new settings, see the updated answer, added the command at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Run: `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

And Change following two settings to
    `yes`

1. `PermitRootLogin yes`
2. `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Now setup root passowd: `sudo passwd root`

Restart SSH: `sudo service sshd restart`

Comment: Greate this work for me after creating so many droplets on digital ocean

Comment: It's conflicting to the answer by @Katie that says `Also check the PasswordAuthentication and make sure it is set to: PasswordAuthentication: no` 
Can you explain why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the root password via the droplet control panel. Then you can SSH into the droplet and add your SSH key.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: I tried using:  ssh-copy-id  -i user.pub root@107.170.209.13  It seems to have worked (there is now an entry in the .ssh/authorized_keys file)  but I'm still being prompted for password at login.