# how to login using ssh root and password

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I have a DigitalOcean droplet that doesn't have my ssh public key on it. I do know the root password, so I want to login using that and add my ssh key. How can I achieve this? Everytime I try to login using `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx` it tells me `Permission denied (publickey).` But then it doesn't prompt me for the root password. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: may be a fail2ban installed, or something wrong in your logins, or other things try a rescue mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help getting my ssh keys to work on a digital ocean droplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475724/need-help-getting-my-ssh-keys-to-work-on-a-digital-ocean-droplet)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an option with DigitalOcean, but you need to enable the "PermitRootLogin" option in the server's sshd config (normally /etc/ssh/sshd_config ) if you really want to log in as root this way.